# HTML img tags won't work in meteor

Tags: html, image, meteor

Its pretty simple, I've looked everywhere and no one has a solution for it. Basically, The html img tags don't seem to work.

```
<img src="../client/app/public/genolagana.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" height="42" width="42">
```

That's my code, And yes, The picture is in the correct file location that I have specified. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Open the page in chrome, right click where you think the image is, then click `Inspect Element`, pay attention especially to the "Network" tab, it will tell you whether the source image is found and accessible.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that and its found with the status of okay and the exact location I have specified but still no picture.

Comment: Then next step is to check whether the `img` width and height are more than 0, I know these are basics, but often times I hit myself with those mistakes.

Comment: Use the elements tab and go to where that is in the code. I would suggest playing around with the CSS stuff in there. also, if it is a profile pic, it may be worth setting it in your css file with `.profile { background-image:url('/genolagana.jpg'}`

Answer (score 4):

Assets are not served from `/client`, put images under `/public/` and just refer to them there with `/public` mapping to `/`

Comment: `/public` should be at app root. You'd refer to an image there with `<img src="/genolagana.jpg">`